# C sscanf("%hhx") read an unsigned int instead of unsigned char

Tags: c, scanf

We use the sscanf() to convert hexadecimal value to string as follows:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
int main() {
    char data[] = "41424344";
    unsigned int result = 0;
    sscanf(data, "%hhx", &result);
    printf("%x\n", result);
    result = 0;
    sscanf(data, "%2x", &result);
    printf("%x\n", result);
    result = 0;
    sscanf(data, "%2hhx", &result);
    printf("%x\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
41424344
41
41
```

From the first output, we can see that `sscanf("%hhx")` read the whole 4 bytes instead of 1 byte ("unsigned char"). why?

Comment: Did you compile with diagnostics on?  With `gcc -Wformat` you get: `warning: format specifies type 'unsigned char *' but the argument has type 'unsigned int *'`  Perhaps that message ought to be enhanced with "this will cause undefined behavior".

Comment: Your code looks more like a test for us to guess what output should be expected than a problem you are having.... Can you please, put what you expect that code to output?  You are calling `scanf` with a `unsigned char` format specifier but instead of passing a pointer to `unsigned char` you pass a pointer to `unsigned int`, and that's **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: By the way, your code cannot conver hexadecimal data into string, as it is scanning a string for numeric data (so is it just the opposite you say?)

Answer (score 4):

*Undefined Behaviour* because of mismatched format specifier and argument type.

According to e.g. [this `scanf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) the `hh` prefix means that the argument needs to be an `unsigned char *`, which is totally different from the `unsigned int *` you pass.

You actually have this problem with the `%2hhx` format as well.

Answer (score 0):

> We use the sscanf() to convert hexadecimal value to string as follows:

Well, your code is everything but a converter between hexadecimal to string.  Your code just accepts a string, and tries to output somewhat based on the conversion of the *interpreted* characters as hexadecimal numbers.  So, If I tie myself to the first paragraph above, a simple solution to that would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *toHexString(
        unsigned value, /* the value to be converted */
        char *buffer,   /* the char buffer to hold the converted data. */
        size_t buf_size)/* the size of the previous buffer */
{
    if (!buf_size) return NULL; /* error, no space in buffer */
    char *p = buffer + buf_size; /* start at the end of buffer */
    *--p = '\0'; /* the string terminator, we go backwards */
    while (value && p > buffer) {
        *--p = "0123456789abcdef"[value & 0xf];
        value >>= 4;
    }
    if (value && p == buffer) { /* overflow */
        return NULL;
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[20];

    /* we should call first the function, to check for NULL
     * return value, but we know a priori that an unsigned
     * int will be less than 20 digits (including the final
     * null char), so we don't need to check for NULL
     * return.
     */
    puts(toHexString(0x12389abcU, buffer, sizeof buffer));
}
```

Sorry for ignoring completely your code, but as written it does nothing, even approximate to what you pretend, converting an hex number (I use an hexadecimal `unsigned int` literal `0x12389abcU`) and print the string (which is in the pointer returned by `toHexString()`).

---

## Note

- Your code doesn't compile with the default compiler parameters.  It gives the following two errors:

```
pru2.c: In function ‘main’:
pru2.c:7:22: error: format ‘%hhx’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned int *’ [-Werror=format=]
    7 |     sscanf(data, "%hhx", &result);
      |                   ~~~^   ~~~~~~~
      |                      |   |
      |                      |   unsigned int *
      |                      unsigned char *
      |                   %x
pru2.c:13:23: error: format ‘%hhx’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned int *’ [-Werror=format=]
   13 |     sscanf(data, "%2hhx", &result);
      |                   ~~~~^   ~~~~~~~
      |                       |   |
      |                       |   unsigned int *
      |                       unsigned char *
      |                   %2x
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
*** Error code 1
```

If I compile it using `--std=c89`, those errors become just warnings and allows to get an executable:

```
lcu@titan:~/git/cornucopia$ make CFLAGS='--std=c89' pru2
cc --std=c89   -o pru2 pru2.c 
pru2.c: In function ‘main’:
pru2.c:7:22: warning: format ‘%hhx’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned int *’ [-Wformat=]
    7 |     sscanf(data, "%hhx", &result);
      |                   ~~~^   ~~~~~~~
      |                      |   |
      |                      |   unsigned int *
      |                      unsigned char *
      |                   %x
pru2.c:13:23: warning: format ‘%hhx’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned int *’ [-Wformat=]
   13 |     sscanf(data, "%2hhx", &result);
      |                   ~~~~^   ~~~~~~~
      |                       |   |
      |                       |   unsigned int *
      |                       unsigned char *
      |                   %2x
```

but after compiling, I get a completely different output:

```
lcu@titan:~/git/cornucopia$ pru2
44
41
41
```

which is not what you state in your question.  By the way, I had to  repair a `#include <string>` into `#include <string.h>` previous error. (are you probably compiling this code with a c++ compiler?)

For this and other reasons, I recommend you to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and once you have read it, **post your question with a code that actually shows what you say.**  If you think we have some magic to guess what you intend, what have you tried, and we have also to correct your typing mistakes on your post, we lose a lot of time with your question, and that's probably good for you, because you learn a lot... but it is horrible for other people that demand help.  Norms and documentation are for being read... not for asking here to get somebody reading them for you.

Next time you post a question.  Please, test the sample code you are going to send, just to check that it doesn't give new errors and warnings that weren't in your testing cases.  And **ONCE YOU HAVE TESTED THE CODE, COPY AND PASTE IT AS IT IS, WITH ALL THE INCLUDE FILES AND EVERYTHING NECESSARY FOR US TO COMPILE AND TEST** If we need to provide everything you get for not needed, you can hide the error in the unposted code, and we'll see nothing strange, but a lot of typing mistakes.